# Unable to get @babel/preset-env to work with node js v6 as target

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm more or less confident that I set up my babel configuration correctly. When I run `./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib` I get `lib` directory created, but for given input (`src/index.js`)

```
// @flow
import functions from 'firebase-functions'

console.log(functions)
```

Produced output is

```
// @flow
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
console.log(functions);
```

Which is incorrect considering I am targeting node v6, that doesn't support `import`

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0-beta.53"
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-flow",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "6.14"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a repo to see the issue in action?